# Prevent message box from popping when run in cmd line

Tags: windows, command-line, popups

I have a [program which creates message boxes when it runs in command line . Is there a command or a way I can disable these message boxes from popping just from the command line .

Comment: Not unless the program itself supports such an option.

Comment: What is the name of the program?  If it is a vbscript, you might be able to run it with cscript.

Comment: its an executable